# Visual Studio 2010 command categories

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In the Visual Studio 2010 Customize->Add Command dialogue, I can select a command from a category.  Given a command name, how do I know which category to look in?  I want to add 'Selection Format' to my code window context menu but I can't seem to find it anywhere I look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what process you can use to find out where it is.

I do know that it is in the **Edit** Category though.

Comment: In 'Edit', I have nothing between 'Selection Comment' and 'Selection Lowercase'

Comment: I only have VS2012 at home to check, but it's there. I would have thought all commands like this would be under "Edit".

Comment: After I did 'reset all settings', 'Selection Format' came back.  Thank-you.